# Closure and property

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, closures

```
var a = "test";
var @delegate = () => a;

Assert.AreEqual(@delegate(),"test"); //true

a = "12345678"

Assert.AreEqual(@delegate(),"test"); //still true, due to closure.
```

However if the variable a were a class level property, what would the second assertion return - true or false?

eg if a were instead

```
string _a;
string a {get {return _a;} set{_a = value;}}
```

If a was a method instead of property, I know the second assert will be false.

Comment: So what the question is?

Comment: The question is, is this any different for property? I know if I were to replace 'a' with a function call 'a()' I will not get the caching effect. Does it work the same way with properties?

Comment: @Alwyn yes, see my answer - a property get is a method call.

Comment: Just curious, why did you not try it yourself?

Answer (score 4):

Closures capture variables, not values.  The second assertion would be false.

Also, it's worth noting that properties *are* methods. A `get` `set` pair of accessors for a property like this

```
private string _a;

public string a
{
    get { return _a; }
    set { _a = value; }
}
```

Actually produces a code like this

```
private string _a;

public string get_a()
{
    return _a;
}

public void set_a(string value)
{
    _a = value;
}
```

The usage of properties like variables is just syntactic sugar

Comment: I thought it copies the memory location - except for the native types. a with the new assignment now points to a different memory location than the a inside the delegate. And yes I understand that property is just syntactic sugar, but does the expression compiler copies a pointer to the value or the function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow. The creation context of the delegate is preserved, so it knows what variable to read from what instance (or more generically scope) to obtain the value it needs - is this not what you mean?

Comment: I don't think so, for some reason the value is caching. Even when the original value has changed, the value inside the expression did not change. I know this with fields, I wanna know if properties is behaving any differently.

Comment: If you would post your actual code it could be helpful in resolving this.

Answer (score 2):

They behave exactly the same.

```
public void ClosureOverVariable()
{
    var a = "x";

    Func<string> d = () => a;

    Console.WriteLine(d()); // print "x"

    a = "y";

    Console.WriteLine(d()); // print "y"
}

class Foo
{
    public string X { get; set; }
}

public void ClosureOverProperty()
{
    var a = new Foo
        {
            X = "a"
        };

    Func<string> d = () => a.X;

    Console.WriteLine(d()); // prints "a"

    a.X = "y";

    Console.WriteLine(d()); // print "y"
}
```